# How to get results one by one 'MySqlDataReader'

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqldatareader

```
using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(0));
    }
}
```

I get few results in same time but i want to get one by one, what i should add?

Comment: When i use MySqlDataReader i get several rows, i want first of them and later rest

Comment: What does that mean? By looping through the reader, you *are* pulling the rows one by one.

Comment: @9ee1 OP sounds like he copied some code off the internet. He sounds like he only wants to call `Read()` _once_.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Perhaps. He never responded, so I guess we will never know :)